# JSon Parse Error: Unable to parse JSON String distance location MYSQL and React Native

Tags: php, mysql, react-native

Have a nice day.

I get JSON parse error error. I guess it's more than the number of numbers. I want to save these outputs to the firebase tables with React native. The output is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1", 
        "CODE": "A1", 
        "distance": "5188.275202003308"
    }
] 
[
    {
        "ID": "1", 
        "CODE": "A1", 
        " distance "" 5188.275202003308 "
    }, 
    {
        " ID ",
        " 2 ",
        "
        CODE ",
        " A2 ",
        " distance ",
        " 6972.949043284923 "
    }
]
```

**React Native Code:**

```
   fetch('http://.../database/KONUM.php')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

 firebase.database().ref('/KONUM/').set(responseJson);

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

MYSQL PHP CODE:

```
<?php
include 'DBConfig.php';    

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);

if ($conn->connect_error) {   

}   


$sql = "SELECT ID,KODU, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( ADRES ) ) * cos( radians( ACIK_ADRES ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( ADRES ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM ....TBL_MUSTERILER 
        HAVING distance < 11125 
        ORDER BY distance 
        LIMIT 0 , 20;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tem = $row;
        $json = json_encode($tem);
        echo $json;
    }
}
else {
    echo "No Results Found.";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: The JSON String appear to be invalid **for multiple reasons**. You can test these strings on a site called jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to build JSON is to make a single PHP data structure, Array or Object and then encode it only when its complete.

Also you can use a method called `fetch_all()` to get all rows in one call.

```
<?php
include 'DBConfig.php';    

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);

if ($conn->connect_error) {   

}   


$sql = "SELECT ID,KODU, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( ADRES ) ) * cos( radians( ACIK_ADRES ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( ADRES ) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM ....TBL_MUSTERILER 
        HAVING distance < 11125 
        ORDER BY distance 
        LIMIT 0 , 20;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $all_rows = $result->fetch_all();
    $all_rows['status'] = "OK";                     // addd a status
} else {
    $all_rows['status'] = "No Results Found.";      // report issue in status
}

echo json_encode($all_rows);


$conn->close();
?>
```

> `fetch_all()` is only availaible if your server has the MySQL Native Driver `mysqlnd` installed.

If it's not you can use

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_all()) {
        $all_rows[] = $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Error code React Native: Json parser error: Unrecognized token '?'

Comment: So can you show the JSON String that is being generated